# Is there a way to only append the changed data of a file instead of overwriting the file using Apache Camel?

Tags: apache-camel

I am new to Apache Camel and I tried to do csv file sync between sftp and local:

```
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {


    public void configure() {

        from("sftp://user@address/location?password=password")
        .to("file:location_dir");     
    }

}
```

The problem is when I insert a new row on a csv file in the source, it will overwrite the file in the destination instead of appending the new row

Is there a way I can append only delta of the file instead of overwriting the file using Apache Camel?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.to("file:location_dir?fileExist=Append")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).